# Android How to excute function1() of a fragment displayed by navigation?

Tags: java, android

Mainactivity has navigationconttoller and some tab pages.
When mainactivity is intented, it get values of  tabPosition and key ( by using putExtra, getExtra).

```java
NavControll.navigate(tabPosition );
```

And then i want to excute function1( key) of the fragment displayed now.
What should i do?

I tried to get the instance but it returned null, so i searched for the solution and then i found getting an instance from nav bad way. So what should I do?

```
TabPageFragment fragment = (TabPageFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(tabPosition );
```